# How can i get a cell with multiple HYPERLINK tags from Google Sheets with GSpread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I need to get links from HYPERLINK'd cell, but i really dont know how i can do it.

I need to get links from HYPERLINK'd cells [Pic. 1] and i cant find any documentation on this problem in GSpread's documentation. The result that i am getting on Pic. 2.
[Problem cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hem2.png)
[Output with different methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AllMD.png)

There is my class that represents google sheet table

```py
class GoogleSpreadSheet:
    def __init__(self, link: str):
        self.link: str = link
        if self.link is None:
            raise Exception("Bad link provided")

        self.gc = gspread.service_account(filename="service_account.json")

        self.sheet = self.gc.open_by_url(self.link).sheet1

    def getAllValues(self, include_header: bool = True):
        if include_header:
            return self.sheet.get_values(value_render_option=ValueRenderOption.formula)
        else:
            return self.sheet.get_values()[1:]

    def getColumnValues(self, column: int, include_header: bool = True):
        """ Column A: Column = 1 """
        if include_header:
            return self.sheet.col_values(column)
        else:
            return self.sheet.col_values(column)[1:]


def load_links_from_file(filename: str):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return [line.strip().replace("\n", "") for line in f.readlines()]
```

There is a `main` function code that trying to get hyperlinks in cell.

```py
def main():
    # Install sheet
    sheet = GoogleSpreadSheet("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GMyZAJkh3hGuNThGCJ4l6NODsqfMjRF2ddJrcpxlD0c")

    # Print out different methods of getting values
    print(sheet.sheet.cell(2, 1, value_render_option=ValueRenderOption.formula).value)
    print(sheet.sheet.cell(2, 1, value_render_option=ValueRenderOption.formatted).value)
    print(sheet.sheet.cell(2, 1, value_render_option=ValueRenderOption.unformatted).value)
    print(sheet.sheet.cell(2, 1).value)
    print(sheet.sheet.cell(2, 1))

    # Outputs
    # Kelli KL-5112 белая озон вб ям сбер
    # Kelli KL-5112 белая озон вб ям сбер
    # Kelli KL-5112 белая озон вб ям сбер
    # Kelli KL-5112 белая озон вб ям сбер
    # <Cell R2C1 'Kelli KL-5112 белая озон вб ям сбер'>


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your sample input situation, it seemed that multiple hyperlinks were put into one cell. And in your script, I guessed that `sheet.sheet.cell()` uses ["Method: spreadsheets.values.get"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). In this case, multiple hyperlinks cannot be retrieved from one cell. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- In order to retrieve multiple hyperlinks from one cell, it is required to use ["Method: spreadsheets.get"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). But, I couldn't find the method of this from gspread. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a sample script using `request` module with the access token retrieved from the client of gspread.

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, from your showing script, the access token is retrieved from the service account. And, it supposes that your service account can access your Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
import gspread
import requests
import urllib.parse


client = gspread.service_account(filename="service_account.json"))

spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set your sheet name.

# 1. Retrieve the access token.
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
client.auth.refresh(request)
access_token = client.auth.token

# 2. Request to the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API using `requests` module.
fields = "sheets(data(rowData(values(formattedValue,hyperlink,textFormatRuns))))"
url = f"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?ranges={urllib.parse.quote(sheetName)}&fields={urllib.parse.quote(fields)}"
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})

# 3. Retrieve the hyperlink.
obj = res.json()
rows = obj["sheets"][0]['data'][0]['rowData']
res = []
for i, r in enumerate(rows):
    temp1 = []
    cols = r.get("values", [])
    for j, c in enumerate(cols):
        a1Notation = gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(i + 1, j + 1)
        if "hyperlink" in c:
            temp1.append({"cell": a1Notation, "hyperlinks": [{"text": c.get("formattedValue", ""), "hyperlink": c.get("hyperlink", "")}]})
        elif "textFormatRuns" in c:
            formattedValue = c.get("formattedValue", "")
            textFormatRuns = c.get("textFormatRuns", [])
            temp2 = {"cell": a1Notation, "hyperlinks": []}
            for k, e in enumerate(textFormatRuns):
                startIdx = e.get("startIndex", 0)
                f = e.get("format", {})
                if "link" in f:
                    temp2["hyperlinks"].append({"text": formattedValue[startIdx:textFormatRuns[k + 1]["startIndex"] if k + 1 < len(textFormatRuns) else len(formattedValue)], "hyperlink": f.get("link", {}).get("uri", "")})
            if temp2["hyperlinks"] != []:
                temp1.append(temp2)
    if temp1 != []:
        res.append(temp1)

print(res)
```

#### Testing:

When the following sample Spreadsheet is used,

[image]

the following result is obtained. You can see that multiple hyperlinks are retrieved from each cell.

```json
[
  [
    {
      "cell": "A1",
      "hyperlinks": [
        { "text": "sample2", "hyperlink": "https://www.google.com/" },
        { "text": "sample3", "hyperlink": "https://stackoverflow.com/" },
        { "text": "sample4", "hyperlink": "https://github.com/" },
        { "text": "sample5", "hyperlink": "https://medium.com/" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "cell": "A2",
      "hyperlinks": [
        { "text": "sample", "hyperlink": "https://www.google.com/" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "cell": "A3",
      "hyperlinks": [
        { "text": "sample2", "hyperlink": "https://www.google.com/" },
        { "text": "sample3", "hyperlink": "https://stackoverflow.com/" },
        { "text": "sample4", "hyperlink": "https://github.com/" },
        { "text": "sample5", "hyperlink": "https://medium.com/" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cell": "B3",
      "hyperlinks": [
        { "text": "sample2", "hyperlink": "https://www.google.com/" },
        { "text": "sample3", "hyperlink": "https://stackoverflow.com/" },
        { "text": "sample4", "hyperlink": "https://github.com/" },
        { "text": "sample5", "hyperlink": "https://medium.com/" }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

#### Reference:

- ["Method: spreadsheets.get"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: @revolex Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.